Generic QuickSort implementation struggles with a lot of strings
I made this quicksort implementation in C for uni that is supposed to be able to receive any type of array and sort it. For a stress test I was provided a records.csv file with 20 million lines structured like this:
<id [int]>,<field1 [string]>,<field2 [int]>,<field3 [float]>

My algorithm has to sort the file lines either by sorting by field1 or field2 or field3 (specified in the user input)
The problem is that, even if sorting by field2 and field3 works perfectly fine (on my machine in 12/13 sec), sorting by field1 causes huge wait time and causes a segmentation fault. This doesn't happen tho if I try and sort a smaller set of lines (I tried 1k) and it works just fine. I also have a mergesort implementation in the same file that works even if it takes like 25 seconds, so I assumed it's not a problem with the csv file.
I'm leaving the sortlib.c file with the algorithm and the mass_test.c file with the csv file reader/writer.
P.S.
the full code is on github at https://github.com/SamueleTondaRoc/SortLib-for-uni
sortlib.h only includes some needed libraries and prototypes for merge_sort and quick_sort
sortlib.c:
#include "sortlib.h"

#define BASE(i) ((base) + ((i) * size))

void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size, void *temp)
{
    memcpy(temp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, temp, size);
}

size_t split(int low, int hig, void *base, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *), void *temp)
{
    int i = low - 1, j = low, mid = low + ((hig - low) / 2), pivot = hig;
    
    if (!((*compar)(BASE(low), BASE(mid)) + (*compar)(BASE(low), BASE(hig))))
        swap(BASE(low), BASE(hig), size, temp);
    else if (!((*compar)(BASE(mid), BASE(low)) + (*compar)(BASE(mid), BASE(hig))))
        swap(BASE(mid), BASE(hig), size, temp);

    while (j < hig)
    {
        if ((*compar)(BASE(j), BASE(pivot)) < 0) 
        {
            i++;
            swap(BASE(i), BASE(j), size, temp);
        }
        j++;
    }
    swap(BASE(i + 1), BASE(pivot), size, temp);
    pivot = i + 1;
    return pivot;
}

/*
    @brief recursive method for the quick sort
*/
void quick_sort_R(int low, int hig, void *base, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *), void *temp)
{
    if (low < hig)
    {
        int pivot = split(low, hig, base, size, compar, temp);
        
        quick_sort_R(low, pivot - 1, base, size, compar, temp);
        quick_sort_R(pivot + 1, hig, base, size, compar, temp);
    }
}

/*
    @brief quick sort for any type of array
    @param base pointer to the first element of the arry
    @param nitems length of the array
    @param size size of array items
    @param compar compare function
    @warning needs a compare function such that if the first elem is "bigger" than the second it returns 1, if it's equal it ret 0, else -1
*/
void quick_sort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) 
{
    void *temp = (void *)malloc(size);
    if (base && compar && nitems)
        quick_sort_R(0, nitems - 1, base, size, compar, temp);
    free(temp);
}

mass_tester.c:
#include "support.h"
#include "../src/sortlib.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct data_line {
    int id;
    char field1[MAX_SIZE];
    int field2;
    float field3;
} Line, *Line_ptr;

size_t calc_csvFile_len(FILE *file)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("calculating file length...\n");
    __clock_t start = clock(), end;

    char s[MAX_SIZE];
    while (fscanf(file, " %99[^\n]", s) == 1)
        len++;

    end = clock();
    double algo_time = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("file length: %ld\nTook: %.2fsec\n\n", len, algo_time);

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    return len;
}

void gather_data(FILE *infile, Line_ptr *data)
{
    int id, field2;
    char field1[MAX_SIZE];
    float field3;

    printf("reading data...\n");
    __clock_t start = clock(), end;

    for (size_t i = 0; !feof(infile); i++)
    {
        fscanf(infile, "%d,%[^,],%d,%f\n", &id, field1, &field2, &field3);
        (*data)[i].id = id;
        strcpy((*data)[i].field1, field1);
        (*data)[i].field2 = field2;
        (*data)[i].field3 = field3;
    }
    fclose(infile);

    end = clock();
    double algo_time = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("data loading complete!\nTook: %.2fsec\n\n", algo_time);
}

void write_data(FILE *outfile, Line_ptr *data, size_t len)
{
    printf("writing data...\n");
    __clock_t start = clock(), end;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        fprintf(outfile, "%d,%s,%d,%f\n", (*data)[i].id, (*data)[i].field1, (*data)[i].field2, (*data)[i].field3);
    }
    fclose(outfile);

    end = clock();
    double algo_time = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("data writing complete!\nTook: %.2fsec\n\n", algo_time);
}

int cmp_field1(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    char A[15], B[15];
    strcpy(A, ((Line_ptr)a)->field1);
    strcpy(B, ((Line_ptr)b)->field1);
    int cmp = strcmp(A, B);
    return cmp > 0 ? 1 : (cmp < 0 ? -1 : 0);
}

int cmp_field2(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int A = ((Line_ptr)a)->field2;
    int B = ((Line_ptr)b)->field2;
    return A < B ? -1 : (A == B ? 0 : 1);
}

int cmp_field3(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    float A = ((Line_ptr)a)->field3;
    float B = ((Line_ptr)b)->field3;
    return A < B ? -1 : (A == B ? 0 : 1);
}

void sort_records(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile, size_t field, size_t algo)
{
    // preparing the array 
    size_t len = calc_csvFile_len(infile);
    Line_ptr data = (Line_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Line) * len);

    // filling the array with data from file
    gather_data(infile, &data);

    printf("sorting...\n");

    // defining compare func
    int (*cmp_func)(const void *, const void *) = field == 1 ? (*cmp_field1) : (field == 2 ? (*cmp_field2) : (*cmp_field3));    

    // chosing sorting algorithm
    __clock_t start = clock(), end;
    if (algo == 1)
        merge_sort((void**)&data, len, sizeof(Line), cmp_func);
    else
        quick_sort((void*)data, len, sizeof(Line), cmp_func);
    end = clock();
    double algo_time = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("array sorted in %.2f seconds\n\n", algo_time);

    // dumping the array data in an output file
    write_data(outfile, &data, len);
    free(data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // reading command
    char *in_file_path = argv[1];
    char *out_file_path = argv[2];
    size_t field = (int)(*argv[3] - '0'),
            algo = (int)(*argv[4] - '0');

    // opening files (the closing happens in the gather_data and write_data methods)
    FILE *infile = NULL, *outfile = NULL;
    if (in_file_path)
        infile = fopen(in_file_path, "r");
    if (out_file_path)
        outfile = fopen(out_file_path, "w");

    // checking inputs and launching sorter
    if (infile && outfile && (field > 0 && field < 4) && (algo > 0 && algo < 3)) 
        sort_records(infile, outfile, field, algo); 
    else 
        printf("error in passed data: \"%s %s %s %ld %ld\"\n", argv[0], in_file_path, out_file_path, field, algo);  // info dump in case of error

    return 0;
}


If your question is about quicksort, did you really need to post the merge sort code? Please post a [mre] so we don't have to wade through lots of irrelevant code.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why while(!feof(file)) is always wrong

Shouldn't #define BASE(i) (*base) + ((i) * size) be parenthesized #define BASE(i) ((*base) + ((i) * size))?

@Barmar that is the approach that was taught to us :/, what would be a better approach?

This fscanf (file, "%[^\n]\n", s); is poor: perhaps fscanf (file, " %[^\n]", s);

Also cmp_field1() includes an additional 800 bytes in A and B compared to cmp_field2(),  cmp_field3(). That alone with a recursive algorithm dealing with 20M records alone could be enough to exhaust memory compared to calls to cmp_field2() or  cmp_field3(). You would have to use a debugger to ensure if that matters. Passing a pointer alone shouldn't cause additional memory use between the 3 functions.

The better approach is in the question I linked to.

Not bug-related, but you're not doing yourself any favors, performance-wise, by allocating a temp buffer for every swap.

...for example while(fscanf (file, " %99[^\n]", s) == 1)

@WeatherVane from what I've tried it works anyways, it shouldn't have to do anything with the problem

But the code doesn't work, that's why you are posting. Every suggestion is gold to me so ty in advance :)

@DavidC.Rankin I forgot about that static 100 i placed there, it was supposed to be for testing, tysm

Other note, just for you, and whoever reads your code later, be wary of nested ternary operators, e.g. cmp > 0 ? 1 : (cmp < 0 ? -1 : 0). They are technically fine, but much harder to read than proper brace-enclosed if (..) else if (...) else with a single return for each. I often use the nested ternary operators to cut down on typing and for a quick conditional -- but those shouldn't be the primary considerations.

@Barmar sorry I didn't notice the link, ty :)

@500-InternalServerError how can I swap otherwise tho?

@WeatherVane I tried it rn and unfortunately that wasn't the fix :(
I'm keeping the () just in case tho

If it is to sort any type, then sorting an array of pointers is more efficient. And the actual data might not be all the same size, for example a string sort.

@DavidC.Rankin oh yeah sorry i should have posted the version where there are if else s; taking note ty

how can I swap otherwise - look into ways to allocate your temp buffer just once before the sort.

@500-InternalServerError ty I didn't think about that earlier, manage to gain 1 second of optimization

@WeatherVane I didn't mention it but the function prototype for the quicksort was
void quick_sort(void base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (compar)(const void, const void));
I don't think i can treat it as an array of pointers
P.S. there was an error in my code where base was a void* even tho it was supposed to be a void*, easy fix since i was basically using a * too much everywhere, sorry I didn't notice earlier

@SamueleTondaRoc I don't think i can treat it as an array of pointers Why not?  The POSIX standard qsort() does just that - see the Linux man page for an example.

@SamueleTondaRoc Tip: Line_ptr data = malloc(sizeof data[0] * len); is easier to code right, review and update than Line_ptr data = (Line_ptr) malloc (sizeof(Line) * len);

@SamueleTondaRoc, for (size_t i = 0; !feof (infile); i++)  { fscanf (infile, "%d,%[^,],%d,%f\n", &id, field1, &field2, &field3);  is bad as id in  (*data)[i].id = id; is used without knowing anything was read.  See this.

Your cmp_field1 has at least two buffer overflow bugs.

@AndrewHenle isn't that example code passing a pointer to the array tho? I'm Genuinely confused on how to move around values trough pointer by just passing the array pointer

The cause for the crash is in function gather_data() on this loop:
for (size_t i = 0; !feof(infile); i++)

Using the function feof() to detect the end of file is not reliable but in your case, the problem is more subtile:
You read the lines with fscanf():
fscanf(infile, "%d,%[^,],%d,%f\n", &id, field1, &field2, &field3);

The problem is you do not test the return value of this function call. It should return 4 if all 4 fields have been correctly read.  Yet if a line in the CSV file does not match the expected format, fscanf() will return a short count (the number of fields it was able to convert, or even EOF if the end of file has been reached before the first conversion) and the firt non matching byte is left pending in the input stream.
If the input file is indeed a CSV file, it may contain a header line with the field names, which will fail the above conversion.  On such files, the loop will continue forever, trying to convert the same header line until it write beyond the end of the array allocated for the database.
Here are steps to correct this problem:

if the CSV file has a header line, it should be skipped (or saved for writing back to the output file)
you should pass the expected number of lines to gather_data
you should read a fill line at a time with fgets() or getline() and attempt to parse it with sscanf()
you should report conversion errors and other inconsistencies when reading the input file.
similarly, you might want to store the input lines in the memory structure so you can write back the same contents (%f will output 6 decimal places, not necessarily the same as the input file).
you should check for and report errors when writing to the output file.
you should check the number of command line arguments received by mass_tester and issue a proper usage message (this is another cause for program failure).

Here is a modified version of mass_testing.c for you to study:
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "../src/sortlib.h"

#define MAX_STR   100
#define LINE_SIZE 100

typedef struct Record {
    char line[LINE_SIZE];
    int id;
    char field1[MAX_STR];
    int field2;
    float field3;
} Record;

int show_timings = 1;

clock_t start_timing(const char *msg)
{
    if (show_timings && msg && *msg) {
        printf("%16s...", msg);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return clock();
}

void stop_timing(clock_t start)
{
    if (show_timings) {
        clock_t end = clock();
        double algo_time = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf(" complete: %.3fsec\n", algo_time);
    }
}

size_t calc_csvFile_len(FILE *file)
{
    clock_t start = start_timing("counting records");

    char buf[LINE_SIZE];
    size_t len = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file))
        len++;

    stop_timing(start);

    return len;
}

size_t gather_data(FILE *infile, Record *data, size_t len)
{
    clock_t start = start_timing("reading records");

    size_t rec = 0;  // number of records read

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int id, field2;
        char field1[MAX_STR];
        float field3;
        char eol[2];

        if (!fgets(data[rec].line, sizeof data[rec].line, infile)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot read line %zu\n", i + 1);
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(data[rec].line, "%d,%99[^,],%d,%f%1[\n]", &id, field1, &field2, &field3, eol) != 5) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid format line %zu: %s\n", i + 1, data[rec].line);
        } else {
            data[rec].id = id;
            strcpy(data[rec].field1, field1);
            data[rec].field2 = field2;
            data[rec].field3 = field3;
            rec++;
        }
    }

    stop_timing(start);
    return rec;
}

int write_data(FILE *outfile, Record *data, size_t len)
{
    clock_t start = start_timing("writing records");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        fputs(data[i].line, outfile);
    }
    if (fflush(outfile)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error writing output file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    stop_timing(start);
    return 0;
}

int cmp_field1(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Record *ap = (const Record *)a;
    const Record *bp = (const Record *)b;
    return strcmp(ap->field1, bp->field1);
}

int cmp_field2(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Record *ap = (const Record *)a;
    const Record *bp = (const Record *)b;
    return ap->field2 < bp->field2 ? -1 :
        ap->field2 > bp->field2 ? 1 : 0;
}

int cmp_field3 (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Record *ap = (const Record *)a;
    const Record *bp = (const Record *)b;
    return ap->field3 < bp->field3 ? -1 :
        ap->field3 > bp->field3 ? 1 : 0;
}

// Helper function to check if array is sorted
int is_sorted(const void *array, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
    const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *)array;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < nitems; i++, p += size) {
        if (compar((const void *)p, (const void *)(p + size)) > 0)
            return 0; // Not sorted
    }
    return 1; // Sorted
}

int sort_records(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile, int field, int algo)
{
    // get the header line (if any)
    char header[LINE_SIZE];
    if (!fgets(header, sizeof header, infile)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "empty file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (*header >= '0' && *header <= '9') {
        // missing header line
        *header = '\0';
        fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    }

    // preparing the array
    size_t len = calc_csvFile_len(infile);
    Record *data = (Record *)calloc(sizeof(Record), len);
    if (data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate line array for %zu records\n", len);
        return 1;
    }

    // rewind the file pointer back to beginning of file
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    // re-read the header if any
    if (*header) {
        fgets(header, sizeof header, infile);
    }

    // filling the array with data from file
    size_t count = gather_data(infile, data, len);

    // defining compare func
    int (*cmp_func)(const void *, const void *) = NULL;
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
        cmp_func = cmp_field1;
        break;
    case 2:
        cmp_func = cmp_field2;
        break;
    case 3:
        cmp_func = cmp_field3;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid sort field %d\n", field);
        return 1;
    }

    clock_t start = start_timing("sorting records");

    // chosing sorting algorithm
    if (algo == 1)
        merge_sort(data, count, sizeof(Record), cmp_func);
    else
        quick_sort(data, count, sizeof(Record), cmp_func);

    if (is_sorted(data, count, sizeof(Record), cmp_func)) {
        stop_timing(start);
        if (*header)
            fputs(header, outfile);
        // dumping the array data in an output file
        int status = write_data(outfile, data, count);
        free(data);
        return status;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "array sorting failure\n");
        free(data);
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./mass_tester input-csv output-csv field algorithm\n"
                "  field: 1,2,3\n"
                "  algorithm: 1,2\n"
                );
        return 1;
    }

    // check command line arguments
    char *in_file_path = argv[1];
    char *out_file_path = argv[2];

    int field = atoi(argv[3]);
    if (field < 1 || field > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid field '%s': must be in range 1..3\n", argv[3]);
        return 1;
    }
    int algo = atoi(argv[4]);
    if (algo < 1 || algo > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid algorithm '%s': must be in range 1..2\n", argv[4]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open files
    FILE *infile = fopen(in_file_path, "r");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", in_file_path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *outfile = fopen(out_file_path, "w");
    if (outfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", out_file_path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // launch sorter
    int status = sort_records(infile, outfile, field, algo);
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);

    return status;
}


This seems strange:
#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct data_line {
    int id;
    char field1[MAX_SIZE];  // So field1 can hold 100 chars
    int field2;
    float field3;
} Line, *Line_ptr;

But later you have:
int cmp_field1 (const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char A[15], B[15];                     // 15 chars per array
    strcpy (A, ((Line_ptr) a) -> field1);  // Potential copy of 100 chars
                                           // into a buffer with only 15 chars
    strcpy (B, ((Line_ptr) b) -> field1);
    int cmp = strcmp (A, B);
    return cmp > 0 ? 1 : (cmp < 0 ? -1 : 0);
}

So depending on the input file it seems you can have a "buffer overflow".
BTW: Sorting based on strings shouldn't require a "special" compare function where strings are copied to other variables. strcmp should do the job by itself. All you should need is a simple wrapper to get the types correct. Like:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct string {
    char string[64];
};

void print_strings(size_t elem, struct string* strings) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elem; ++i) puts(strings[i].string);
}

// Simple compare function for strings
int strings_cmp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return strcmp(((struct string*)a)->string, ((struct string*)b)->string);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct string strings[] = {
        {"def"},
        {"mnop"},
        {"ghijkl"},
        {"abc"}
    };
    size_t elem = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    
    puts("---- Before qsort ----");
    print_strings(elem, strings);
    
    qsort(strings, elem, sizeof *strings, strings_cmp);
    
    puts("---- After qsort  ----");
    print_strings(elem, strings);
    
    return 0;
}

Output:
---- Before qsort ----
def
mnop
ghijkl
abc
---- After qsort  ----
abc
def
ghijkl
mnop


I tried doing int cmp = strcmp (((Line_ptr) a) -> field1, ((Line_ptr) b) -> field1); but that doesn't seem to fix the problem, it still runs for a long time and ends up in segmentstion fault. No more buffers tho

@SamueleTondaRoc Well... then there are more bugs. Maybe I'll take a look later but at least you got one bug solved.

I created a decent test suite today and the code has no problem with arrays of int, char, floats, doubles, strings, structs. I don't get what the problem could be tho. maybe a memory leak?
